# PLS-00049 bad bind variable when compiling a trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I'm trying to implement a dedupe trigger to a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER.TBL_ACTION_DEDUP
BEFORE INSERT
ON USER.ERRORTABLE 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
   IF (:OLD.Identifier = :NEW.Identifier) THEN  
      SELECT :OLD.tally + 1 INTO :NEW.tally FROM DUAL;
   END IF;  
END TBL_ACTION_DEDUP;
/
```

Error is: 
On line:  2
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.IDENTIFIER'

Comment: What is the old value of IDENTIFIER and TALLY if you insert a new row? Old values only exist for update and delete triggers.

Comment: Why are you using a `select ... from dual` to assign the new value? Much better just to do `:new.tally = :old.tally + 1;`.

Comment: Why use the `referencing` clause if you're just going to use the same names? Delete that clause entirely.

Comment: What do you mean by "dedupe trigger"? It looks like you mean you want to update an existing row in the situation where the user tries to insert a new row with the same key. This isn't possible with a *trigger* on a *table* in Oracle because the insert will still happen.

Answer (score -2):

you should remove fragment: "USER.". Properly is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TBL_ACTION_DEDUP
BEFORE INSERT
ON ERRORTABLE 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
IF (:OLD.Identifier = :NEW.Identifier) THEN  
  SELECT :OLD.tally + 1 INTO :NEW.tally FROM DUAL;
END IF;  
END TBL_ACTION_DEDUP;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Franek, it worked. But I have a question. The intention of doing this trigger is to implement dedup, but when I tried to input two similar rows, it returns the error "ORA-00001: unique constraint (UPM_USER.PKEY_ERRORID) violated". I am expecting this will not happen because the trigger will automatically dedup my entry.

Comment: I suppose primary key PKEY_ERRORID doesn't contain column TALLY. You should extend this primary key.

Comment: Hmm, after rethink you should query also for old tally because in this trigger shape old nothing return. SELECT tally + 1 INTO :NEW.tally FROM ERRORTABLE where identifier = : NEW.identifier